# How to display image icon with image name in gridview

Tags: android

I have images saved as jpg in the app. folder on the sdcard. Below code pulls the images in the gridview. Using gridview I want to show image icon in the gridview along with the name of the image. How can I achieve that? Thanks

```
ImageAdapter myImageAdapter;
GridView gridview;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.my_layout);

      gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        myImageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this);
        gridview.setAdapter(myImageAdapter);


        String ExternalStorageDirectoryPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(); 
        String targetPath = ExternalStorageDirectoryPath + "/MyApp/";


         File targetDirectory = new File(targetPath);
        File[] files = targetDirectory.listFiles();
        for (File file : files){


         myImageAdapter.add(file.getAbsolutePath());

        }
```

// my_layout.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >



 <GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to put your images into arrays

Comment: Following link could help you worked for me http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2013/02/display-images-in-gridview.html#.VCtWelWSwb4

Comment: its more of a comment rather than the answer